# Finding the path of a specific WordPress install

Tags: wordpress

I have recently taken over a WordPress website.

Once I got access to the server I found that there were more than 70 installations of WordPress spread across it (files and DBs).

What is the quickest/easiest way for me to determine which installation is the one that is running the actual live website?

I thought of putting a PHP file into each installation (a file that echoed something along the lines of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`) - then try and access that file from the site itself, from there I know which installation is the correct one (I can then work out which DB is the correct one from the wp-config).

But surely there is an easier way?  I have access to wp-admin, is there anything I can do in there to show me the base install path of this particular WordPress?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Comment: @Banzay ...and to which of the 70 installations of WordPress do I add that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Save the follwoing code into a php file and put it into the root foler. This will list all the folders which have the WordPress installation.

```
<?php 

$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');

foreach($dirs as $dir)
{
    $path=$dir.'/wp-config.php';
    if(file_exists($path))
    {
        echo $dir.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I find out which WordPress install is being used by the Server?